# How to get modified files and lines impacted at a given revision with mercurial style?

Tags: mercurial, diff

I am trying to extract the files impacted by a revision and the changed lines in those files with mercurial.

So far, I've the list of files with :

```
hg log --stat -p -r R --style my_style
```

my_style

```
changeset = "{date|hgdate}\n{files}\n"
file = "{file}\n"
```

Here's an output example :

```
1200467360 0

groovy.editor/src/org/netbeans/modules/groovy/editor/lexer/GroovyLexer.java

1 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

diff -r a72d4e87d6cf -r 260a269563c6 groovy.editor/src/org/netbeans/modules/groovy/editor/lexer/GroovyLexer.java
--- a/groovy.editor/src/org/netbeans/modules/groovy/editor/lexer/GroovyLexer.java   Wed Jan 16 06:16:32 2008 +0000
+++ b/groovy.editor/src/org/netbeans/modules/groovy/editor/lexer/GroovyLexer.java   Wed Jan 16 07:09:20 2008 +0000
@@ -112,7 +112,7 @@
             if (antlrToken != null) {
                 int intId = antlrToken.getType();

-                int len = lexerInput.readLength() - myCharBuffer.getExtraCharCount();
+                int len = lexerInput.readLengthEOF() - myCharBuffer.getExtraCharCount();
                 if ( antlrToken.getText() != null ) {
                     len = Math.max( len, antlrToken.getText().length() );
                 }
@@ -129,7 +129,8 @@
                     }
                 }

-                if ( scanner.getStringCtorState() != 0) {
+                // state 8 occured with '}' character closing expression in gstring
+                if ( scanner.getStringCtorState() != 0 && scanner.getStringCtorState() != 8) {
                     intId = GroovyTokenTypes.STRING_LITERAL;
                 }
```

What I would like is something similar to:

```
1200467360 0
  groovy.editor/src/org/netbeans/modules/groovy/editor/lexer/GroovyLexer.java @@ -112,7 +112,7 @@ @@ -129,7 +129,8 @@
```

Is there a way to achieve that in the style file ? If not, what will be the best way to achieve it ?

Comment: So you are just trying to get the line range of the changes?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't have a better idea that using unix tools to transform your output into what you want. Do you know how to do that?